# normal subgroup question

Tags: abstract-algebra

Assume that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ with   $[G∶ H] = 2$. Prove that if $x,y ∈ G$ and $x,y ∉ H$, then $xy ∈ H$.

I know that $H$ is closed, but I can only used closure property for elements in $H$ but $x,y ∉ H$. How can I show  $xy ∈ H$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints:

We know $\,G=H\cup gH\,\;,\;\;\color{red}{g\notin H}\,$ , and $x,y\notin H\implies x= gh_1\;,\;y=gh_2\; $. But then

$$xy=(gh_1)(gh_2)$$

But if $\,xy\notin H\, $ , then

$$xy=gh_3\implies gh_1gh_2=gh_3\implies h_1gh_2=h_3\implies \color{red}{g\in H}$$

getting a straightforward contradiction.

Of course, your claim follows almost immediately from *normal* subgroups, quotient subgroups and stuff, but I'm assuming you still don't know/cannot use this stuff.

Comment: A smooth way leading to contradiction. +1

Comment: That's what I call a sexy proof :p

Comment: Thanks for the proof. I learned about quotient subgroup and know that $(xH)(yH)=(xyH$, but how can I use it in this problem ? Would you show me please.

Comment: I don't think you need that here, @DianeVanderwaif : for one, neither your question nor my answer even mentions that $\,H\,$ is normal in $\,G\,$, which is true in this case of course. We only work with pretty basic stuff: left cosets and their definitions.

Comment: ok then, Thank you very much for a great proof.

Answer (score 1):

$y\notin H\Leftrightarrow y^{-1}\notin H$, so $G=H\cup xH=H\cup y^{-1}H$ and so $xH=y^{-1}H$.

Answer (score 1):

$H$ is of index $2$ and so it is normal. Then $G / H$ is the cyclic group of order two and so $(x H)(y H) = H$ since both $x$ and $y$ are not in $H$.